# Explain meaning "Who was the last person to be drunk/high at work"

Tags: meaning, phrases

This is a question from a type of "card against humanity" game.

Our disagreement is between two definitions:
A. Last (most recent) person chronologically to show up/get drunk at work
B. Least likely person to be drunk at work

Comment: Most recent . . .

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the question

> Who **was** the last person to be drunk/high at work?

But you have left out the final question mark, so I'm not fully confident on the reply.

Generally, the "last person who **was** *A*" would be someone who was *A* in the past, and the last one in the historical sequence, thus the most recent.

On the other hand, if the question had been,

> Who **would be** the last person to be *A*?

you would be asking for the last person in the list of people you would expect to be *A*, which would be the one least expected.